# How to get over the fear of flight?

Tags: air-travel

I have recently got a new job, it's all good except that it will require me to travel frequently,5 hours trip once every month at least.

My fear isn't during the take off and landing like most people have, nor for a crash or anything like it.

I get my anxiety during the cruise, when the plane is all level and smooth, it's more like a fear of heights but I don't have that actually.

Have anybody ever get this type of fear? How can I get over it, I tried sleeping but I can't sleep on planes, the maximum amount of sleep I ever got on a plane was half an hour during a 15 hours trip.

This is not a duplicate or related to the mentioned question. I am not afraid of the sounds the airplane makes or maneuvers, I am not even afraid of turbulence and had many flights with very turbulent weather to the extent that one flight attendant fell on the floor, and bags started to fall from their places, my fear and anxiety didn't increase during these times at all

Answer (score 1):

***(This is my personal experience from flying 4-5 times a year)***

It may differ from person to person, but my girlfriend always takes a pill against seasickness before takeoff (not because she gets sick, but because she has anxiety). It lasts around 5 hours and makes her really sleepy and she has that "I don't care"-feeling.
After taking the pill, she tries to sleep (almost always successfully). However, the negative thing is that she is tired almost the whole day after taking it. BUT it prevents her from overreacting while on flight.

[image]

It's a german product, but you may find something appropiate in your country.

Comment: Your tablets appear to be dimenhydrinate (Dramamine), a common motion-sickness drug. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimenhydrinate

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I have tried some meds before and it didn't work except when I take sleeping pills, that obviously knocks me out but makes me groggy for the entire day, which isn't an option for me as most of these trips are only a one day trip, get on the plane, arrive at destination and attend to work, back to the plane and back home

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically say that your fear does not arise from thoughts that the plane may crash, etc., most answers that relate to fear of flying will not apply to you.

I speculate that your anxiety is more of a social nature. You are in a situation where you sit with many others who are rarely talking. This is different from travelling on a train because its a lot quieter on an airplane and the absence of conversation is more noticeable. You can try to start a conversation with the passenger next to you, but that doesn't always work out. I think its best to immerse yourself in other activities you like, e.g. reading a book, sleeping, watching something on the flight entertainment system, working on your laptop, gaming on your tablet. Keep yourself busy with something. Your brain will then have less time to cook up unpleasant scenarios.

PS: Resort to medication only after you have exhausted all other methods of controlling your fear.

Comment: I don't think it stems from a social nature, I don't speak with people that much and if I don't have to talk or hear anybody chatting around me that would make me happy and relaxed.
As for meds, I tried them before after speaking to a psychiatrist but it didn't do much, except for the sleeping pills.